# Pandas merging data and overwrite a column

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two DataFrames, with the first being my main df and the second being one I want to 'update' the first with.

Essentially, I have the following:

```
In [205]: df1
Out[205]: 
         date  total
0  04/10/2016     10
1  04/10/2016     20
2  04/10/2016     30
3  04/10/2016     40
4  04/10/2016     50

In [206]: df2
Out[206]: 
         date  new
0  04/11/2016    1
1  04/11/2016    2
2  04/11/2016    3
```

When I merge, I get two date columns.

```
In [207]: pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
Out[207]: 
       date_x  total      date_y  new
0  04/10/2016     10  04/11/2016  1.0
1  04/10/2016     20  04/11/2016  2.0
2  04/10/2016     30  04/11/2016  3.0
3  04/10/2016     40         NaN  NaN
4  04/10/2016     50         NaN  NaN
```

Is there anyway, that I can just overwrite the original `date` column in `df1`?

Right now, I would do:

```
In [209]: df3['date_x'].update(df3['date_y'])

In [210]: df3
Out[210]: 
       date_x  total      date_y  new
0  04/11/2016     10  04/11/2016  1.0
1  04/11/2016     20  04/11/2016  2.0
2  04/11/2016     30  04/11/2016  3.0
3  04/10/2016     40         NaN  NaN
4  04/10/2016     50         NaN  NaN
```

and try to drop the `date_y` but that doesn't seem very efficient.

I have also tried `combine_first`, but in some cases that gives me undesirable results (i.e. if my original date is blank, and I combine a new one to it.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, and here is the documentation for [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
In [154]: pd.merge(df2, df1, left_index=True, right_index=True, on='date', how='outer')
Out[154]:
         date  total  new
0  04/11/2016     10    1
1  04/11/2016     20    2
2  04/11/2016     30    3
3  04/10/2016     40  NaN
4  04/10/2016     50  NaN
```

Comment: This doesn't overwrite the date in `df1`, which is the goal here

Comment: If it is as simple as that then `df1['date'] = df['date']` shall do, is it not helping?

Comment: Sorry, I tried `pd.merge(df, df1, left_index=True, right_index=True, on='date', how='outer')`, but doing `pd.merge(df2, df1, left_index=True, right_index=True, on='date', how='outer')` worked for me. I hadn't thought to put the second dataframe as the intial argument.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: If you edit your solution to that, I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: one more thing for clarity, if you could change the first 3 dates to be `04/11/2016` like in my `df3['date_x']` example. Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108753/discussion-between-nighthallow-and-abbas).